# Error: failed to compile tikz to pdf

Tags: knitr

On my friends Windows pc, then running any type of plots with knitr outputting with dev='tikz' I get an error.

It works with dev='pdf'.

It does output the file "foo-1.tikz" and this can be compiled fine on its own, however when using knitr by

```
knit("temp.Rnw")
```

then it

```
processing file: temp.Rnw
  |......................                                           |  33%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...........................................                      | 67%
label: foo (with options)
List of 2
$ fig.height: num 4
$ dev       : chr "tikz"

Creating new TikZ metrics dictionary at:
    temp-tikzDictionary
Using TikZ metrics dictionary at:
    temp-tikzDictionary
Quitting from lines 9-13 (temp.Rnw)
Error: failed to compile figure/foo-1.tikz to PDF
```

I have no idea what can be wrong and where to look for a solution. Somehow knitr cannot find out how to call pdflatex or something.

Can anyone give my a hint how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

I've found a workaround thanks to [this report on the knitr Github repo](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1181).

Set the chunk option `external=FALSE`. With this option, `knitr` does not run the compilation of the files `xxx.tikz`. Instead, it includes them in the LaTeX file like this:

```
\begin{knitrout}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.969, 0.969, 0.969}
\input{figure/myplot-1.tikz}
\end{knitrout}
```

The problem with this way is that the chunk option `out.width` is ignored, and the figures can be so big that they go in the margins and even beyond.

But you can control the figure size like this in the Rnw, by using `scalebox`:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\scalebox{0.5}{
<<myplot, echo=FALSE, fig.width=10, fig.height=6, dev='tikz', external=FALSE>>=
…….
@
}
\end{figure}
```

Oddly, the `dev.args` chunk option causes a crash (I tried e.g. `dev.args=list(width=3,height=3)` to set the dimensions), while it is supposed to pass the arguments to the device.